# Гарантирует ли данный код уникальность элемента по отношению к массиву?

Tags: php

Создаю ключи с помощью `$unique = uniqid()` 
Однако, [согласно тестам](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29974146/multiple-uniqid-calls-not-being-unique), это не гарантирует 100% уникальность.  
`$arr` - многомерный массив, выгруженный из базы данных 
Необходимо гарантированно создавать уникальный ключ по отношению ко всем другим ключам. 
**Гарантирует ли уникальность такой перебор и сравнение с каждым существующим ключем?** 
`uniqid()` отсчитывает только вперед, поэтому количество прогонов = количество элементов в массиве.
Это самая грубая ситуация, когда вообще все элементы совпали =)

```
$arr = R::getAll('SELECT `title` FROM `itemscategory` WHERE `id_user` = 100'); 

$unique = "5e9dfcc49a460"; // существующий key 

  for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
    if (!in_array(['title' => $unique], $arr)) {
      echo $unique;
      echo "  <- "; 
      echo " Уникальное";
      break;
    } else {
      echo $unique;
      echo "  <- ";
      echo " Есть дубль";
      echo " \n ";
      $unique = uniqid();
    }
}

   // Итого выводится на странице:
   // 5e9dfcc49a460  <-  Есть дубль 
   // 5e9e22f523312  <-  Уникальное
```

**var_dump($arr**)

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["title"]=>
    string(13) "5e9dfcc295981"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["title"]=>
    string(13) "5e9dfcc49a460"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    ["title"]=>
    string(13) "5e9dfcc5b1ff8"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(1) {
    ["title"]=>
    string(13) "5e9dfcc637f75"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Если вопрос в этом:

> Гарантирует ли уникальность такой перебор и сравнение с каждым существующим ключем?

То да, уникальность такой метод гарантирует, однако, **не до бесконечного числа итераций**.

Comment: Почему не до бесконечного? Как добиться уникальности до бесконечного числа итераций?

Comment: @VanilJS А оно вам нафига?

Comment: Бессмысленный ответ..

Comment: "Почему не до бесконечного? " - так заложено в логике поведения uniqid(). В документации написано (и так и есть), что в основу значения ложится метка времени. В большинстве случаев, это не критично.
"Как добиться уникальности до бесконечного числа итераций" - Не знаю ,чем Вам не подходит стандартный вариант генерации уникального значения по A_U из БД? 
Либо солить свой ключ, A_U значением из MYSQL